# Shrink rows of one column with the same other column Linux

Tags: linux, bash

i have data in following form:

```
a, 1
a, 2
a, 3
b, 4
b, 5
b, 6
```

I would like to achieve it in the following form using bash commands:

```
a, "[1, 2, 3]"
b, "[4, 5, 6]"
```

the thing with the quotes and square brackets is not that relevant as just having in second column a collection of items having the same value in the first one.

Comment: Did you try anything already? Did you have a strategy in mind?

Comment: I am an idealist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely in-efficient way (you should use `awk` or `perl`)

```
file="file.txt"
while read -r k
do
    printf '%s, "[%s]"\n' "$k" "$(paste -sd, <(grep -oP "^$k\s*,\s*\K.*" "$file"))"
done < <(cut -d, -f1 "$file" | sort -u)
```

output:

```
a, "[1,2,3]"
b, "[4,5,6]"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### form.txt

```
a, 1
a, 2
a, 3
b, 4
b, 5
b, 6
```

#### script.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

set -o errexit # Exit if there is an error

form=${1?"Expected form as argument"}

while read -r line; do
  cmd="${line/,[[:space:]]/+=(})"; # replace line with "var+=(val)"
  eval ${cmd}; # Process the command, add the value to the array.
done < "${form}"

while read -r array; do
  eval echo "${array} [\${$array[@]}]"; # Should print array (val val val)
done < <(cut -f1 -d"," "${form}" | sort | uniq) # Get all the array names
```

This script should do what you want.

Comment: You should test again. "local can only be used in functions". Also, if my file name has a space or glob character in it, this breaks.

Comment: Currently (after fixing the `local` issue), this just prints `/1 /4` (on two lines).